# How to do Hive SQL IF/ELSE query?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

In my Hive SQL script I want to do:

IF {$user_choice = 1}
SELECT a,b,c FROM Table1;
ELSE
SELECT d,e,f FROM Table1;

Where user_choice is a parameter that Hive prompts for when the query is run.

What's the right syntax for this please? Or is there another way to achieve the same thing if I'm thinking about it wrong?

I'm trying to do this via the Hue editor, if that makes a difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column types are the same, you can use CASE statements or UNION ALL in Hive:

```
SELECT 
      case when ${user_choice} = 1 the a else d end col1 
      case when ${user_choice} = 1 the b else e end col2 
      case when ${user_choice} = 1 the c else f end col3 
  FROM table1;
```

OR

```
SELECT  a, b, c FROM table1 WHERE ${user_choice} = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  d, e, f FROM table1 WHERE ${user_choice} = 2
```

And if the data types of columns are different, or completely different scripts then call hive from shell

```
if if [[ ${user_choice}  == "1" ]] ; then 
  hive -e "query one"
else 
  hive -e "query two" 
fi
```

Column names also can be parametrized: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55805764/2700344

Comment: That's very helpful thank you. Couple of questions please:
1.) My column types are the same, but in the case of the second user option I want to show a subset of all columns that the first user options displays. I've used the UNION ALL method above but want to hide the unused columns in the 2nd option, the closest I can manage is specifying columns as "SELECT null AS column_name", but is it possible to specify a column in the SELECT (to make UNION ALL work) but then hide it from the output?

Comment: 2.) With the script option, I'm having to use Hue and Oozie, I suppose in the Oozie workflow I would have a script action, but would I then also need a decision node and other nodes to branch to my full or partial query, or would the script handle the decision and branch so the workflow would consist only of a single node to run the script? Thanks again.